# Using worksheetfunction in VBA without activating the Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the following code to determine the next empty row on a worksheet:

```
emptyrow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B:B")) + 1
```

However, I have noticed that it only works when the page I want to use is activated. I have tried using with statements as so:

```
With MyWorksheet
emptyrow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B:B")) + 1
End With
```

But realized almost as soon as I had finished typing it that that isn't the correct usage of with. How can I perform worksheetfunctions without activating the worksheet? I am looping through many worksheets and don't want each to activate. Thanks!

Comment: You're missing the leading period which ties your `Range` to the worksheet object: `WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("B:B")) + 1`  This (using CountA) is not reliable if you might have empty cells in your data though...

Comment: `Set MyWorksheet = Worksheets("Name")` instead of  `Set MyWorksheet = ActiveWorksheet`

Comment: Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you! I should have thought of that.

Comment: @UGP I already do    Set MyWorksheet = Worksheets("Name")

Answer (score 1):

As TimWilliams said in his comment, I just had to add a period before

```
range
```

to make it

```
.range
```

and it works.